# Is there a way to associate members of a loop generated list that are objects with specific values?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, graphics

I am trying to use graphics.py to make simple graphics that can be used as buttons. Though I know how to do this by individual drawing of each object and association to a letter or number, I am using a loop to generate the objects. I am lost on how to go about associating each object created with a specific letter or number.

Below is some code that I have been working on to attempt to find a solution to this problem. The loop functions work to create graphics as well as to detect mouse clicks in them. Where I am lost is how to assign each member of the list a specific assignment of a letter or number. The code below generates three circles that I would like to associate with letters A,B,C respectively so that when clicked, they draw the letter above the graphic.

```
from graphics import*
import string
def main():
    window = GraphWin("Window", 400, 400)
    circles1 = keys(window)
    # line here to call upon function that draws labels over
    # the circles using ascii string removed for relevance
    # test for clicking circles
    while True:
        clickPoint=window.checkMouse()
        if clickPoint != None:
            for i in circles1:
                if mouse(clickPoint, i) == True:
                    i.undraw()
                    # i.undraw used to test while loop


def keys(window):
    # Define circles as an empty list
    circles = []
    x = 50
    for i in range(3):
        x += 50
        circle = Circle(Point(0+x, 100), 20)
        circle.setFill("black")
        circles.append(circle)
        circle.draw(window)
    return circles



def mouse(point, circle):
   x = point.getX()
   y = point.getY()
   radius = circle.getRadius()
   center = circle.getCenter()
   cx = center.getX()
   cy = center.getY()
   distance=(((cx-x)**2)+((cy-y)**2))**0.5
   if (distance < radius):
       return True
    else:
        return False
```

Ideally, clicking on a button would draw the letter it is assigned to above it. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can iter over `string.ascii_lowercase`
Now, you return an array, but it looks like more pythonic to use `generator`

```py
from graphics import*
import string

def keys(window):
    for letter, index in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
        x = 50*(index+1)
        circle=Circle(Point(0+x,100),20)
        circle.setFill("black")
        # Do what you need with Letter
        circle.draw(window)
        yield circle
```

If this code is confusing, I kindly suggest you document yourself about:

- Generator and `yield` keyword (some resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do))
- `enumerate` function (you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/))

With those two stuff in mind, you just need to now `string.ascii_lowercase` will return `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. I'll let you guess what `string.ascii_uppercase` returns

Comment: I understand the thought process behind this but I am getting a value error for the line "for letter, index in string.ascii_lowercase:" " ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: Forgot the `enumerate` on the for loop....
Response has been edited